# Null response on Post json object in body of retrofit in kotlin

Tags: android, mysql, json, kotlin, retrofit

I want to post json object to mysql, it runs well in Postman but in android studio it shows 403 error and null response body.

these are my codes

Endpoint

```
@Headers("Content-Type: application/json; charset=urf-8")
@POST("cart")
fun pesanMenu(@Body data: JsonObject): Call<JsonObject>
```

Request

```
val jsonParent = JsonObject()
        jsonParent.addProperty("id_user",sID)
        jsonParent.addProperty("alamat_antar","Lewat Android")

        val all_product_list = dbHandler?.task()

        val jsonArrayPesanan = JsonArray()
        for (pesan in all_product_list!!) {
            val jsonPesanan = JsonObject()
            jsonPesanan.addProperty("id_menu", pesan.id)
            jsonPesanan.addProperty("price", pesan.priceCart)
            jsonPesanan.addProperty("quantity", pesan.quantityCart)

            jsonArrayPesanan.add(jsonPesanan)
        }

        jsonParent.add("pesanan",jsonArrayPesanan)

        Log.i("JSON", jsonParent.toString())

        InitRetrofit().getInstance().pesanMenu(jsonParent).enqueue(object : Callback<JsonObject> {

            override fun onFailure(call: Call<JsonObject>, t: Throwable) {
//                    t.printStackTrace()
                Log.d("RETRO", "Falure : " + "Gagal Mengirim Request")
            }

            override fun onResponse(call: Call<JsonObject>, response: Response<JsonObject>) {
                Log.d("RETRO", "Berhasil : " + "Berhasil Mengirim Request")
//                Log.e("TAG", "response 33: " + Gson().toJson(response.body()))
                val result = response.code()

                Log.d("PesanActivity", "response = $result")
            }

        })
```